# Sharing strings to other native applications not working in react native

Tags: react-native

I have been following [this](https://codecookbook.co/post/how-to-share-text-from-your-react-native-app/) tutorial, however, when I go to run the application after dropping the code in, it doesn't seem to work. The tutorial seems fairly simple, so I can not understand why it is not working.

The error message I'm getting is:

[image]

```
import React from 'react'

import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Share } from 'react-native'    

class ShareLesson extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._shareMessage = this._shareMessage.bind(this);
    this._showResult = this._showResult.bind(this);
    this.state = { result: ''};
  }

  _showResult(result) {
    this.setState({result});
  }

  _shareMessage() {
    Share.share({
      message: 'This is a simple shared message'
    }).then(this._showResult);
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._shareMessage}>
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    Share
                  </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <Text>
            {JSON.stringify(this.state.result)}
          </Text>
        <View>);
  }
}
```

## Tabs Component

```
class Tabs extends Component {
  _changeTab (i) {
    const { changeTab } = this.props
    changeTab(i)
  }
  _renderTabContent (key) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'today':
        return <Home />
      case 'share':
        return <Share />
      case 'savequote':
        return <SaveQuote />
      case 'moremenu':
        return <MoreMenu />
    }
  }
  render () {
    const tabs = this.props.tabs.tabs.map((tab, i) => {
      return (
        <TabBarIOS.Item key={tab.key}
          icon={tab.icon}
          selectedIcon={tab.selectedIcon}
          title={tab.title}
          onPress={() => this._changeTab(i)}
          selected={this.props.tabs.index === i}>
          {this._renderTabContent(tab.key)}
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
      )
    })
    return (
      <TabBarIOS tintColor='black'>
        {tabs}
      </TabBarIOS>
    )
  }
}

export default Tabs
```

Comment: Do you have a Tabs component? That's where the error is coming from

Comment: @MattAft Question updated.

Comment: How are you exporting/importing your components inside _renderTabContent?

Comment: `import Share from '../components/Share'
import SaveQuote from '../components/SaveQuote'
import Home from '../containers/navRootContainer'
import MoreMenu from '../components/MoreMenu'`

Above the `Class Tabs extends Component`

Comment: In all those files, make sure there is `export default` in front of class, so for ShareLesson it would be `export default class ShareLesson extends Component`